# fixing a CSS dropdown menu

Tags: css

Can you help me making appear sub menus perfectly under main menus and not aside? Rest of the code is here  https://jsfiddle.net/1547pdw7/2/

```
      <div id="sidebar"><ul>
        <li><a href="#">AAAAAA</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">BBBBBBB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CCCCCCC</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DDDD</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">TRFDS</a>
    <ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `#sidebar ul ul` remove `position: absolute;` and add `padding: 0;`

https://jsfiddle.net/1547pdw7/10/

Comment: No problem, glad to help!